# JMX Client needing MBean interface

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans

I am new to JMX technology and if I understand correctly:
There are 2 ways to invoke operation on Mbeans:

1) TO use the invoke operation of MBeanServerConnection and provide the method name as a String using `mbsc.invoke(name, operationName, params, signature)`

2) Get the MBean interface using `JMX.newMBeanProxy(connection, objectName, interfaceClass)` and call the operations on interface.

My question is that if I want to use the second approach mentioned above, do I need to have the Mbean interface in my client also? The Mbean interface is part of source of my main application that is to be monitored. Do I need to copy the same Mbean interface into the client code as well?

Comment: Yes you need. It's passed as third parameter to the method `interfaceClass`.

Comment: But to make my client independent of the agent(application to be monitored), what is the best practice? Should I keep my Mbean interfaces in a separate jar file and let the client and agent have that jar file imported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me there is no `best practice`, as the decision depends on your needs.

Find below my personal opinions.

`mbsc.invoke(name, operationName, params, signature)`

If the client application is not strictly dependent on the application where the MBean is executed, the client application should not depend on the interface. Take as example the `jconsole` utility. It can invoke all exposed operations without the need to have access to the mbean interface class.

`JMX.newMBeanProxy(connection, objectName, interfaceClass)`

If the client application has a strong dependency to the application where the MBean is executed (e.g. you provide the application with the mbean, and the client application is your support tool), I would go for this solution as you get the benefit of compile time checks.

Comment: Thanks, so it is clear to me know that there are two way to implement a client. One is for it to be independent of application and other will be that client is dependent on mbean interfaces of application.